# Extend multilevel dataframe using existing index name with reindex Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The objective is deepen existing multiindex `df`.

Such that, given a `df` as below

```
                                     col1      col2
mylevelA_caseA__VAR_A   bar one -1.012046  0.808332
mylevelA_caseA__VAR_B   bar two -0.558629 -0.358550
mylevelA_caseB__VAR_A   baz one  1.514448 -1.045073
mylevelA_caseB__VAR_B   baz two  1.268511 -1.100705
mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C   foo one -2.108172 -1.694602
mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C_D foo two -0.629493 -0.005071
mylevelB_caseC__VAR_E   qux one  0.596771 -0.964429
mylevelB_caseD__VAR_A   qux two  0.257154 -0.248278
```

I would like to extend the multilevel index into something like.

[image]

At this stage, please note that at the first index level, there are double `__` before keyword `VAR`.

To achieve something similar to the figure above, the following code is drafted

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [["mylevelA_caseA__VAR_A", "mylevelA_caseA__VAR_B", "mylevelA_caseB__VAR_A",
           "mylevelA_caseB__VAR_B", "mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C", "mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C_D",
           "mylevelB_caseC__VAR_E", "mylevelB_caseD__VAR_A"],
          ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
  ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"]]


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=arrays,columns=['col1','col2'])
# print(df)

idx_ls=df.index.values.tolist()
new_multiindex=[]
for x in idx_ls:
    b=x[0]
    vv=b.split('_')
    c=[]
    new_data=[]
    mvar=[]
    for xx in vv:
        if not c:
            if xx:
                new_data.append(xx)
            else:
                c=1
        else:
            if xx:
                mvar.append(xx)


    ntuple=(*new_data,"_ ".join(mvar),*x )
    new_multiindex.append(ntuple)
    t=1

df=df.reindex(ne

w_multiindex,copy=True)
print(df)
```

Which produced

```
                                                          col1  col2
mylevelA caseA VAR_ A    mylevelA_caseA__VAR_A   bar one   NaN   NaN
               VAR_ B    mylevelA_caseA__VAR_B   bar two   NaN   NaN
         caseB VAR_ A    mylevelA_caseB__VAR_A   baz one   NaN   NaN
               VAR_ B    mylevelA_caseB__VAR_B   baz two   NaN   NaN
mylevelB caseC VAR_ C    mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C   foo one   NaN   NaN
               VAR_ C_ D mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C_D foo two   NaN   NaN
               VAR_ E    mylevelB_caseC__VAR_E   qux one   NaN   NaN
         caseD VAR_ A    mylevelB_caseD__VAR_A   qux two   NaN   NaN
```

There are two issue.

First: the `col1` and `col2` return `nan`

Second: May I know whether there is more compact way to minimise the line of code within the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a small list comprehension on the index and make a new multiindex:

```
import re
from itertools import chain
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(chain(re.split('__?', e[0], maxsplit=2),
                                                  e[1:]))
                                      for e in df.index])
```

Or a simpler version:

```
import re
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([re.split('__?',e[0], maxsplit=2)+list(e[1:])
                                      for e in df.index])
```

output:

```
                                    col1      col2
mylevelA caseA VAR_A   bar one -0.327934 -0.071217
               VAR_B   bar two -0.344340  0.969293
         caseB VAR_A   baz one  0.536292 -0.000917
               VAR_B   baz two  0.632327 -0.493869
mylevelB caseC VAR_C   foo one -0.253687  0.543698
               VAR_C_D foo two -0.239579  1.188864
               VAR_E   qux one -1.450289 -0.756109
         caseD VAR_A   qux two  1.213411  1.237863
```

To include the original long index:

```
import re
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([re.split('__?',e[0], maxsplit=2)+list(e)
                                      for e in df.index])
```

Custom split (splits all '_' until '__'):

```
def custom_split(s):
    a,b = s.split('__')
    return a.split('_')+[b]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([custom_split(e[0])+list(e)
                                      for e in df.index])
```

Comment: This is neat. But, just wonder if you could offer two solution whereby the other one include the original long name (e.g., mylevelA_caseA__VAR_A).

Comment: @balandongiv see the last piece of code in the updated answer

Comment: For future reader, the `maxsplit=2` need to be treated with extra care. For example, maintaining `maxsplit=2`  for index-name such as `mylevelA_caseA_AnotherLevel__VAR_A` will give different output.

Comment: Would you prefer to split everything before "__"?

Comment: oN second thought, this restrict me to maintain all index_name to have similar number of  `_` before the `Var`. Combining `mylevelA_caseA_AnotherLevel__VAR_A` and mylevelA_caseA__VAR_A will give different output.

Comment: Hi @mozyay. The only reason there is double `_` before `var` is to indicate no splitting by `_` occur after that

Comment: @balandongiv then you could split first on "__" and then resplit the left part. But I agree that it's better to keep clean than to try to generalize

Comment: Nevertheless, I added an example

Answer (score 1):

You can also, try this:

```
df.set_index(
    df.index.get_level_values(0).str.split("_", n=3, expand=True), append=True
).droplevel(5).reorder_levels([3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2])
```

Output:

```
                                                            col1      col2
mylevelA caseA VAR_A   mylevelA_caseA__VAR_A   bar one  2.925263  0.065379
               VAR_B   mylevelA_caseA__VAR_B   bar two -1.544370  0.383090
         caseB VAR_A   mylevelA_caseB__VAR_A   baz one -0.260279 -0.264885
               VAR_B   mylevelA_caseB__VAR_B   baz two  0.071172 -0.201748
mylevelB caseC VAR_C   mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C   foo one -0.319578 -0.909871
               VAR_C_D mylevelB_caseC__VAR_C_D foo two -1.058169 -0.465444
               VAR_E   mylevelB_caseC__VAR_E   qux one -0.432982 -1.999376
         caseD VAR_A   mylevelB_caseD__VAR_A   qux two -0.704989 -0.298849
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Scoot. But, I have to accept the other alternative since it generalise `bonus` requirement, which is after thought after posting this OP

Comment: @balandongiv No problem.  Happy coding!  Be safe and stay healthy.

Comment: I would like to endorse your Linkedn in return, but somehow I'm unable to find endorsement for `pandas`

Comment: @balandongiv No problem.  Just connect with me. :-)